# Float Values as an index in an Array in C++

Tags: c++

Can a float value be used as the index of an array? What will happen if an expression used as an index resulted to a float value?

Comment: A very bad idea because of rounding errors. However, sometimes this is useful, but then the value should be converted into integer first and bounds-checking (or limiting) be done before accessing. This operation can be useful e.g. for approximating values for a floating-point function using a lookup table.

Answer (score 12):

The float value will be casted to int (it can give warning or error depending on compiler's warning level)

```
s1 = q[12.2]; // same as q[12]
s2 = q[12.999999]; // same as q[12]
s3 = q[12.1/6.2]; // same as q[1]
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes. But it's pointless. The float value will be truncated to an integer.

(You can use `std::map<float, T>`, however, but most of the time you'll miss the intended values because of inaccuracy.)

Comment: As for inaccuracy, I think there should be some way to provide your own compare function where you can include an 'epsilon'... a tolerance of sorts.

Comment: And of course you could also use unordered_map for more performance if the order doesn't matter. In this case you have to include epsilon in the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

A C++ array is a contiguous sequence of memory locations. `a[x]` means "the xth memory location after one pointed to by `a`."

What would it mean to access the 12.4th object in a sequence?

Comment: Note to pedants: yes, I know array offsets are not a simple addition of integers to pointers: this sentence assumes that a "memory location" is the size of an array member, so for an int a[], a[5] means the fifth word, not the fifth byte.

Answer (score 1):

It will be casted to int.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error. In `[expr.sub]`:

> A postﬁx expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postﬁx expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type.

I am not aware of a clause in the standard that specifies that conversion should happen here (admittedly, I would not be surprised if such a clause existed), although testing with ideone.com did produce a compilation error.

However, if you're subscripting a class rather than a pointer — e.g. `std::vector` or `std::array`  — then the overload of `operator[]` will have the usual semantics of a function call, and floating-point arguments will get converted to the corresponding `size_type`.