# Why does moving for loops to their own function slow down the program?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a small diffusion simulation that I'm experimenting with speeding up.
Here is the 'naive' version:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

std::chrono::nanoseconds diffuse_naive(std::vector<double> &c,
                            std::vector<double> &c_tmp,
                            const double T,
                            const double dt,
                            const double aux) {
    const size_t num_steps = (T / dt) + 1;
    const size_t length = sqrt(c.size());
    // M = N + 2, the length with padding
    const int M = (int) length;
    auto time_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t step = 0; step < num_steps; ++step) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < length - 1; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 1; j < length - 1; ++j) {
                c_tmp[i * M + j] = c[i * M + j] + aux * (
                    c[i * M + (j + 1)] + c[i * M + (j - 1)] +
                    c[(i + 1) * M + j] + c[(i - 1) * M + j] -
                    4 * c[i * M + j]);
            }
        }
        std::swap(c, c_tmp);
    }
    auto time_stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time_stop - time_start);
    return time_elapsed;
}
```

I was originally experimenting with the use of `const` and `__restrict` to speed this up, and in doing so, moved the inner `for` loops to their own function:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

void step_const_c(const std::vector<double> &__restrict c,
                    std::vector<double> &__restrict c_tmp,
                    const size_t &length,
                    const double &M,
                    const double &aux) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length - 1; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 1; j < length - 1; ++j) {
            c_tmp[i * M + j] = c[i * M + j] + aux * (
                c[i * M + (j + 1)] + c[i * M + (j - 1)] +
                c[(i + 1) * M + j] + c[(i - 1) * M + j] -
                4 * c[i * M + j]);
        }
    }
}

std::chrono::nanoseconds diffuse_const_c(std::vector<double> &c,
                            std::vector<double> &c_tmp,
                            const double T,
                            const double dt,
                            const double aux) {
    const size_t num_steps = (T / dt) + 1;
    const size_t length = sqrt(c.size());
    // M = N + 2, the length with padding
    const int M = (int) length;
    auto time_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t step = 0; step < num_steps; ++step) {
        step_const_c(c, c_tmp, length, M, aux);
        std::swap(c, c_tmp);
    }
    auto time_stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time_stop - time_start);
    return time_elapsed;
}
```

Both are compiled with `g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14 -o diffusion diffusion.cpp` and run with `./diffusion 0.1 2.0 200 0.5 1 naive` and `./diffusion 0.1 2.0 200 0.5 1 const` respectively.

As pointed out by a comment below, the use of `__restrict` is pretty pointless when using vectors, so I ran this both with and without the use of `const` and `__restrict`. The runtime with the separate for-loop function increases by a factor of six, from 0.05 seconds with the naive approach to 0.3 seconds when calling `step_const_c` (with or without `const` and `__restrict`).

What is causing the version with the inner `for` loops in their own function to be so much slower than having the `for` loops in the same function?
Thanks!

**Edit**: This question was originally about why adding `const` and `__restrict` slowed the program down, but I removed `const` and `__restrict` from the arguments of `step_const_c`, and the runtime was pretty much identical, which indicates they aren't the issue, but rather putting the `for` loops in their own function.

The full content of `diffusion.cpp`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


void save_results(const std::vector<double> &c,
                    const std::string &implementation) {
    std::string filename = "cpp_" + implementation + ".txt";
    size_t length = sqrt(c.size());
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ofstream::out);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
            ofs << c[i * length + j];
            if (j == length - 1) {
                ofs << "\n";
            } else {
                ofs << ",";
            }
        }
    }
    ofs.close();
}


void step_const_c(const std::vector<double> &__restrict c,
                    std::vector<double> &__restrict c_tmp,
                    const size_t &length,
                    const double &M,
                    const double &aux) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length - 1; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 1; j < length - 1; ++j) {
            c_tmp[i * M + j] = c[i * M + j] + aux * (
                c[i * M + (j + 1)] + c[i * M + (j - 1)] +
                c[(i + 1) * M + j] + c[(i - 1) * M + j] -
                4 * c[i * M + j]);
        }
    }
}


std::chrono::nanoseconds diffuse_const_c(std::vector<double> &c,
                            std::vector<double> &c_tmp,
                            const double T,
                            const double dt,
                            const double aux) {
    const size_t num_steps = (T / dt) + 1;
    const size_t length = sqrt(c.size());
    // M = N + 2, the length with padding
    const int M = (int) length;
    auto time_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t step = 0; step < num_steps; ++step) {
        step_const_c(c, c_tmp, length, M, aux);
        std::swap(c, c_tmp);
    }
    auto time_stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time_stop - time_start);
    return time_elapsed;
}


std::chrono::nanoseconds diffuse_naive(std::vector<double> &c,
                            std::vector<double> &c_tmp,
                            const double T,
                            const double dt,
                            const double aux) {
    const size_t num_steps = (T / dt) + 1;
    const size_t length = sqrt(c.size());
    // M = N + 2, the length with padding
    const int M = (int) length;
    auto time_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t step = 0; step < num_steps; ++step) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < length - 1; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 1; j < length - 1; ++j) {
                c_tmp[i * M + j] = c[i * M + j] + aux * (
                    c[i * M + (j + 1)] + c[i * M + (j - 1)] +
                    c[(i + 1) * M + j] + c[(i - 1) * M + j] -
                    4 * c[i * M + j]);
            }
        }
        std::swap(c, c_tmp);
    }
    auto time_stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(time_stop - time_start);
    return time_elapsed;
}


void initialize_concentration(std::vector<double> &c,
                                const double &L,
                                const size_t &N,
                                const double &h) {
    const double bound = 0.125 * L;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            if (std::abs(i * h - 0.5 * L) < bound &&
                std::abs(j * h - 0.5 * L) < bound) {
                c[(i + 1) * (N + 2) + (j + 1)] = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 7) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s D L N T out implementation\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const double D = std::stod(argv[1]);        // diffusion constant
    const double L = std::stod(argv[2]);        // domain size
    const size_t N = std::stoul(argv[3]);       // number of grid points along each dim
    const double T = std::stod(argv[4]);        // simulation time in seconds
    const size_t output = std::stoul(argv[5]);  // whether to store results, yes == 1
    const std::string implementation = argv[6]; // version of program to run

    const double h = L / (N - 1);               // length between grid elements
    const double dt = h * h / (4 * D);          // maximum timestamp for numeric stability
    const double aux = dt * D / (h * h);        // all constant terms in diffusion equation

    std::vector<double> c((N+2) * (N+2), 0.0);
    std::vector<double> c_tmp((N+2) * (N+2), 0.0);
    initialize_concentration(c, L, N, h);
    std::chrono::nanoseconds time_elapsed;
    if (implementation.compare("naive") == 0) {
        time_elapsed = diffuse_naive(c, c_tmp, T, dt, aux);
    } else if (implementation.compare("const") == 0) {
        time_elapsed = diffuse_const_c(c, c_tmp, T, dt, aux);
    }
    printf("Elapsed time: %luns\n", time_elapsed.count());
    if (output == 1) {
        save_results(c, implementation);
    }
}
```

Comment: `__restrict` is useless, the compiler knows the vectors do not overlap.

Comment: I'll edit the post to indicate that the issue doesn't seem to be `const` or `__restrict`, but rather calling the inner loops as a separate function.

Comment: not the issue, but you should not use `std::high_resolution_clock`. See notes here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

Comment: Nice catch, I switched over to steady_clock in my local implementation

Comment: @273K I changed the example such that step_const_c uses double* __restrict and pass vector::data(). It improves by ~8% on my machine, so it seems there is a difference. I think also logically it makes sense. step_const_c could be called as step_const_c(c,c, length, M, aux) with the same vector for both parameters, so the compiler cannot assume that the data of the vectors does not overlap.

Comment: In your case all is in a single file and the compiler knows the function is not invoked as `step_const_c(c,c, length, M, aux)`.

Comment: Yes, but the compiler seems to choose to not make use of this knowledge :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was implicit typecasting happening (I think)!

`diffuse_const_c()` declares `M` as an `const int &`, but `step_const_c()` was requesting `const double &M`.
I'm far from experienced in C++, but if I had to guess what's happening under the hood, I would assume two additional steps are being added that are slowing this down:

1. Create a new anonymous integer variable
2. Cast `M` and place it in that variable

Considering the rest of the function is just grabbing values from a pre-allocated vector, some quick algebra, then putting the result back into a pre-allocated vector, these additional steps sound relatively expensive.

Switching the function argument in `step_const_c()` to `const int &M` brings the runtime down to the same level as the naive implementation.

Comment: I think that is actually the reason. I changed the code a bit to use double pointers to check if __restrict would provide some improvement, and then you get compiler errors with double M: https://godbolt.org/z/8nx56bG8K. I think with double M, calculation of array indexes is done with double arithmetics instead of integer. If you compile with -Wconversion you will see many warnings about conversions between double and size_type / size_t.

Comment: Ah, and `std::vector`'s indexer [seems to be able to index floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310838/float-values-as-an-index-in-an-array-in-c), so without `-Wconversion`, it was silently (and slowly) doing all the conversions in the background. And yes, I definitely need to go back now and clean up all the new warning for mismatched types. Thanks!